# Android Studio: Las comillas de apertura se deben utilizar para el atributo 'X' asociado a un tipo de elemento 'x'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Me ocurre el siguiente error y no se a que se deba:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 25; Las comillas de apertura se deben utilizar para el atributo "xmlns:android" asociado a un tipo de elemento "manifest".

Este es el manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<manifest 
xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
package="com.example.myapplication">

<application android:allowBackup="true" 
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" 
    android:supportsRtl="true" 
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> 

<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"> 
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
    </intent-filter>
 </activity> 

</application> 
</manifest>
```

Comment: Hola Isaac. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Has de poner un titulo más descriptivo para futuros users que busquen problemas similares. tambien explica que intentas que hizo que saliera el error. Mira [ask] para hacer mejores preguntas. Un saludo

Comment: necesito restablecer android studio para que funcione el emulador

Comment: Estoy haciendo mis primeras incursiones con ejercicios de youtube

Comment: Si ese es el manifest el que publicastes pero en la linea xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; //yo tengo//  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Answer (score 4):

Tienes `AndroidManifest` bastante liado, los problemas son:

- `xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";` ese **;** del
  final sobra.
- Esto no es correcto    `schemas.android.com/apk/res/android`, lo
  correcto en este caso sería
  `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android`

Te dejo aquí como deberías tenerlo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: lo copie tal cual pero sigue Execution failed

Comment: Enseña el error completo que te marca ahora @Isaac

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 25; Las comillas de apertura se deben utilizar para el atributo "xmlns:android" asociado a un tipo de elemento "manifest".

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 25; Las comillas de apertura se deben utilizar para el atributo "xmlns:android" asociado a un tipo de elemento "manifest".

Answer (score 0):

Como complemento, los namespaces definidos en los .xml deben iniciar con `http://` y no llevan `;`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<manifest 
xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
package="com.example.myapplication">
```

por lo tanto esto debe ser lo correcto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapplication">
```

AndroidManifest.xml completo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.myapplication">

  <application android:allowBackup="true" 
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" 
    android:supportsRtl="true" 
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> 

<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"> 
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
    </intent-filter>
 </activity> 

</application> 
</manifest>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64912/discussion-on-answer-by-jorgesys-android-studio-las-comillas-de-apertura-se-deb).

Comment: Gracias por pasarme la dirección del blog, ya solucione el problema he hice el ejemplo del blog, el error que tenia estaba en la API de compilado nuevamente Gracias!!